# How To Create This RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to find this in a string: XXXX-XXX-XXX Where the X is any number.

I need to find this in a string using JavaScript so bonus points to those who can provide me the JavaScript too. I tried to create a regex and came out with this: `^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}$`

Also, I would love to know of any cheat sheets or programs you guys use to create your regular expressions.

Comment: I tried to create a regex and came out with this: ^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}$

Comment: Why the down votes as this is a reasonable question? @AmitBhargava Your answer is incorrect as you need to escape the hyphens to work as literals since hyphens are a syntax character in regex.

Comment: @AmitBhargava Your regexp was fine. No need to escape hyphens. @austincheney You're wrong. Hyphens have no special function outside `[]`.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Have you tested this cross browser?  Try testing it in IE7 or IE8.  As far as I know any syntax character in Regex is processed explicitly if not escaped regardless of whether that syntax character is a metacharacter.  In some browsers though, you just get lucky.  Does the spec say something contrary?

Comment: @austincheney Regular expressions are actually explicitly defined in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). See section 15.10 "RegExp (Regular Expression) Objects".

Comment: @AdamZalcman Could you be more specific?  Section 15.10 gets closest to your point by stating a classAtom of a single value plus a hyphen should return the hyphen as a literal, but it does not go on to describe the hyphen outside of a classAtomic notation.  15.10 is more than 10 pages so if you were attempting to prove me wrong you could have done more than merely looked up the table of contents.  See section 15.10.2.17.

Comment: @austincheney Section 15.10.1 contains the grammar. Why are you looking at `classAtom`? That refers to a character class in `[]`. See definition of `Atom` and `PatternCharacter`. The point is that `PatternCharacter` may be a hyphen: `SourceCharacter` may be any Unicode character (as defined in a few other places in the document) and hyphen is not excluded from `PatternCharacter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[i suppose this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck3pm/):

```
\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}
```

in doubt? Google for "RegEx Testers"

Comment: You need to escape the hyphens as they are a syntax character in regex.

Comment: @austincheney for real? [it works *without* escaping dashes](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck3pm/)

Comment: are you sure that applies outside of character sets?

Comment: @Austincheney: Really? Do you have a reference handy?

Comment: @austincheney really? do you have docs for this? i tested on IE **6** and it works.

Answer (score 1):

With your attempt:

```
^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}$
```

Since the `-` is not a metacharacter, there is no need to escape it -- thus you are looking for explicit backslash characters.

Also, you've anchored the match at the beginning and end of the string -- this will match only strings that consist *only* of your number. (Well, assuming the rest were correct.)

I know most people like the `{3}` style of counting, but when the thing being matched is a single digit, I find this more legible:

```
\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d
```

Obviously if you wanted to extend this to matching hexadecimal digits, extending this one would be horrible, but I think this is far more legible than alternatives:

```
\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}
[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}
```

Go with whatever is easiest for you to read.

I tend to use the `perlre(1)` manpage as my main reference, knowing full well that it is far more featureful than many regexp engines. I'm prepared to handle the differences considering how conveniently available the `perlre` manpage is on most systems.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = (/\d{4}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}/).exec(myString);
```

Comment: -1 for spreading misinformation about the need to escape hyphens.

Comment: @AdamZalcman now you are being petty.  I replied to your comment above.